# Polymorphic relation in Eloquent ORM (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, inheritance, ember.js, polymorphism, eloquent

I am trying to achieve an inheritance by using polymorphic relations in Eloquent ORM.

My model schema looks like this:

```
class Section extends Model {
    public function blocks() { // section has many blocks }
}
abstract class Block extends Model {..}
class Exercise extends Block {..}
class Info extends Block {..}
```

So in my case Section has an array of blocks (and each element could be Exercise or Info).

I tried to tell Eloquent that **Section.blocks** is an *hasMany* relation to **Block**, and **Block** is *morphedTo* by it's **blockable** relation to **Exercise or Info**, but i failed (and it also doesn't seem like a proper way to do it, because it creates one additional property like `$section->blocks[0]->blockable`, which should be `$section->blocks[0]` ).

I also tried to *morphTo* from **Section.blocks** right away, but also failed.

Maybe somebody already achived that, and could point me towards right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague but your models should be like below. If there are any difference then add exact errors you get when you fail.

```
class Section extends Model {
    public function blocks() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Exercise extends Block {
    public function sections() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Section', 'blocks');
    }
}

class Info extends Block {
    public function sections() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Section', 'blocks');
    }
}
```

Comment: What I get from `section->relations->blocks` is **null**.  This is how my db schema looks like: [db schema](http://imgur.com/Mf0nDtj)

Comment: If you have info object and you want to get Section then you can do it with $info->sections

Comment: No no, I want to get list (array) of blocks of an section (which by polymorphism would be Info or Exercise).

Like this: `section->blocks`

Comment: I see, if you want to have ploymorphic many to many relationship then it is a bit different. With my example `$section->blocks` gives you only one block You need to follow this guide very closely http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations